# MongoDB clients stopped connecting to secondary nodes of the replicaset

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

Application stopped connecting to the mongodb secondary replicaset. We have the read preference set to secondary.

mongodb://db0.example.com,db1.example.com,db2.example.com/?replicaSet=myRepl&readPreference=secondary&maxStalenessSeconds=120

Connections always go to the primary overloading the primary node. This issue started after restarting patching and restart of the servers.

Tried mongo shell connectvity using above resulting in command being abruptly terminated. I see the process for that connect in the server in ps -ef|grep mongo

Any one faced this issue? Any troubleshooting tips are appreciated. Log's aren't showing anything related to the terminated/stopped connection process.

Comment: What's the result of `rs.status()`?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the issue. It was an issue on the spring boot side. When the right bean (we have two beans - one for primary and one for secondary connections) was injected, the connection was established to the secondary node for heavy reading and reporting purposes.